# Does golel for first torah stand for second torah?

Tags: halacha, torah-service, kaddish, standing-sitting, hagbah-gelilah

When there are two or three sifrei torah read on the same day, either the magbiah or golel holds the first sefer while the second is read. In this case should he stand for…

1. kadish after reading from the second sefer?
2. Hagbah for the second sefer?

I have no halachik reason to think he should/shouldn’t, I just think that I’ve seen most people sit through both and I can’t figure out why.

There have been a bunch of suggestions in the comments section that he doesn't stand out of respect to the second sefer (Why should one have to stand for the other?). I like the answer, but if some sort of authoritative source could be found that would be better.

Comment: I've never seen the golel hold it.

Comment: I did this morning (as in I did gelilah and then held the torah) and i've seen it before

Comment: I agree it's certainly possible. I imagine the reason he doesn't stand is it wouldn't be kavod to the first Torah to move it because of the second Torah. Why is one better than the other? Also, you might think that the first one is pasul or something.

Comment: @Community Sure there can be, such as weekday Chol HaMoed Pesach or a weekday Rosh Chodesh Tevet.

Comment: @Double AA- There can be what?

Comment: @AriA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/15641/2

Comment: no source, but maybe we don't want a Torah standing up for another?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15641/does-golel-for-first-torah-stand-for-second-tora#comment31482_15641

Comment: I don't have a source (so I'm not putting this in the answer section), but since you asked the question I paid more attention to what we do in my shul (a Young Israel with a very yeshivishe rabbi and largely yeshivishe membership). We put the first Sefer Torah on the table along side the second (or third) Sefer Torah, and the Ba'al Korei says kaddish standing in front of both (or all) of them together. This eliminates the conundrum posed by your question of whether the holder of the first Sefer Torah should rise for kaddish. The holder does not, however, rise for the second hagba'a.

Comment: I remember some years ago when I was given hagbah on a day when there were two sifre torah. I started to stand for the second hagbah and the rabbi very emphatically motioned for me to sit back down. I can assure you I haven't done that since.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Chidah in [Shu"t Chaim Sha'al 1:71:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=821&st=&pgnum=128&hilite=) brings down that if one is sitting and holding a sefer Torah and a Rebbe passes by one should not get up.

Also, I believe if one sits with a Torah during hakafos it is fine.

Comment: The Steipler in his old age would hold a mini-Torah during Hakafot, so that he may sit while other Sifrei Torah were circling.

Answer (score 1):

In sefer Tshuvos Avigdor Halevi (Rav Nebontzal) page 181:46 he was asked does the one who did hagbah have to stand when the shatz says kaddish after uvo l'tzion(sefard) if he always stands? He answers no since the Torah does not have to get up.

Comment: Presumably this _shita_ would apply to "_Bar'chu_" also; wanna post an answer to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68971?