# Sitting when holding a Sefer Torah during Torah Reading

Tags: halacha, minhag, torah-reading, standing-sitting

When there are two Sifrei Torah taken out on a particular Shabbas, the tradition in many shuls is to have the second safer Torah be held by by one of the congregants sitting down while the first one is being read.

It is also true that [many hold](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56372/standing-for-barchu-during-laining) that there is a obligation to stand for at least part of the Torah Reading.

From what I have seen in most congregations the man who is holding the second safer torah does not stand for any part of the first safer torah being read. Does anyone have a source for why that is?

Comment: Well for one thing, if he would stand, than everyone would be required to stand as a matter of respect to that Torah which is no longer resting.

Comment: @user6591, eh, maybe. See http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5770/korach.html (the paragraph that begins "[When the Torah is not “in motion”").

Comment: @msh210 I think your own source and footnote that only exempts the sick and weak deserves better than an "eh maybe":)

Comment: Which part of the Torah reading is there a obligation to stand during??

Comment: As someone who frequently is tasked with holding the second (or third) sefer, I'm makpid to sit, as our minyon doesn't require members to stand for any bakashot. Further, I believe that there are shittot which don't require standing for Barachu of Shacharit (michomer vekal, this would apply to קריה"ת)

Answer (score 4):

[Sam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1418/sam) wrote this as an answer to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15641/9643):

> In sefer Tshuvos Avigdor Halevi (Rav Nebontzal) page 181:46 he was asked does the one who did hagbah have to stand when the shatz says kaddish after uvo l'tzion (sefard) if he always stands? He answers no since the Torah does not have to get up.

Presumably, this would also apply to *Barchu* said by *Krias HaTorah*. (*[msh210](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15641/does-golel-for-first-torah-stand-for-second-torah#comment197685_17923)*)